# Cassandra: Blob data type in Csssandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

I was working on a requirement for creating a table reference_files in cassandra with below few points-

```
     content_id - primary key
     my_id - cluster key
```

1-  Each blob in the table will have a max size of 5 MB, and the max size of a row will be 200 MB

2- The my_id will be a counter for keeping track of the order in which the file chunks should be put back together

My solution-

```
       create table reference_files(
         content_id text,
         my_id int,
         content blob
    );
```

With reference to datastax document max blob size is 2 GB. Can somebody tell me did i committed any mistake in my implementation?

Comment: You are using content_id as a partition key, which means your per file data is not going to be distributed across Cassandra nodes and you may potentially run into hotspots.

Comment: may want to consider storing blobs in something like s3 or a distributed file system and just having references to them in the database. Other wise +1 what yurgis said, put `PRIMARY KEY ((content_id, my_id))` so that way my_id is part of a composite partition key so chunks will distributed.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Isnt it the other way around? If he creates content_id partitions with my_id clustering he will have all chunks in one partition on one node?

Comment: @MatijaGobec With the inner parentheses in the primary key, your designating a composite partition key. So the my_id would be part of the partitioning not the clustering key. It will be distributed on all the nodes.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Looks like I'm dyslexic... Didn't see the double parentheses.